# Tensorflow Saver.Save(), FailedPreconditionError, Failed to rename: ... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tried to use Saver to save a session. And encountered an error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Failed to rename: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15754770084434331914 to: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
; Broken pipe
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, model/Variable/_121, model/embedding, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias/_123, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/_125, model/softmax_b/_127, model/softmax_w/_129)]]
```

Here is the code:

```
saver.save(session, "./Language_model_lab3", global_step=i)
```

And here is the full report:

```
saver.save(session, "./Language_model_lab3", global_step=i)
error: Failed to rename: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15754770084434331914 to: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
; Broken pipe
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, model/Variable/_121, model/embedding, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias/_123, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/_125, model/softmax_b/_127, model/softmax_w/_129)]]

Caused by op 'save/SaveV2', defined at:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_launcher.py", line 78, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 2483, in debug
    exec_file(file, globals_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 111, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 87, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\zhaoy\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestTf\TestTf\ML120\PTB\Lab3-LangugageModel.py", line 277, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1218, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1227, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1263, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 748, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 296, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 239, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1162, in save_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, tensors=tensors, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Failed to rename: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate15754770084434331914 to: ./Language_model_lab3-0.data-00000-of-00001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
; Broken pipe
     [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, model/Variable/_121, model/embedding, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias/_123, model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/_125, model/softmax_b/_127, model/softmax_w/_129)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched this site, the only answer is related to dropbox and I don't have dropbox running. Turned of Symantic anti-virus, Mircosoft Onedrive and Google Backup/Sync. Not helping.

I tried to use " Process Explore" to search which process has the file / folder locked and can't find any.

So I tried  this in the "immediated Window": ( a trick so I can test something without restarting the program)

And it worked.

```
saver.save(session, "./Language_model_lab3/", global_step=i)
'./Language_model_lab3/-0'
```

if I add an file name:

```
saver.save(session, "./Language_model_lab3/Model.ckpt", global_step=i)
'./Language_model_lab3/Model.ckpt-0'
```

So I solved it by using a specific subfolder for my code. No sure why. :)

I posted here as I can't found similar solution online.

Comment: I have a similar problem but it didnt work by making another folder and saving the file there as I expected! You have probably done something else because your solution doesn't make sense!

Comment: every time this happens to me i spend 5 hours debugging and come back to this answer. Thank you! what i get for putting my working directory on dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to when I was changing some files inside the project or when I created one while the program was running. Be sure you are not changing any sittings of your IDE while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade TensorFlow. It worked for me in similar case.